# Finding matching data point within two images using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I am have having two images, namely Fig 1 and Fig 2. Both taken from the same source but not aligned. The task is to find the common data point among these two images and draw lines between the data points that match in both the images., I am looking at this figure should be like Fig 4.

So far, I have used OpenCV and written the following codes:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_file1= "Fig_1.png"
img_file2= "Fig_2.png"
img1= cv2.imread(img_file1)
img2= cv2.imread(img_file2)
    
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

figure, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 8))

ax[0].imshow(img1, cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(img2, cmap='gray')

#sift
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

#feature matching
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(descriptors_1,descriptors_2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints_1, img2, keypoints_2, matches[:50], img2, flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

This gives to be not expected result, see figure 4. Plus look quite messy and unclear.

Can anyone help me with how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Fig 1

[image]

Fig 2
[image]

img3

[image]

Fig 3

[image]

Comment: What does fig 3 represent ? Your output from the above code ?

Comment: Yes, fig 3 represent the output from my code (img3).

Comment: My guess is that as the feature to be detected is just white circles, the feature detector detects circle and as the image is full of similar features (i.e) white circles, the matcher was not able to match it appropriately.

Comment: Try running the code with a different example like the one shown in the opencv docs (https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) and check if you are getting similar results.

Comment: Tried but getting a similar result. fig3 seems added images together, How can I make the distance between these two so that I can clearly see which data points belong to which one?

Answer (score 2):

The transformation seems purely translational. Try template matching by normalized grayscale correlation.

Comment: How to do this. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Ravi: search for Template matching in the doc.

Comment: @YvesDaoust He is trying to find the common data points between the two images and match them. What should be the template in this case ?

Comment: @Kishore: the whole image minus a translation allowance.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this seems to me a registration problem (the images need to be registered).

Here is what you can do:

1. find the location of the points with [connected components analysis](https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/08-connected-components.html)
2. calculate the shift needed to [register the two images](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.registration.html). Here it seems your images are only translated, so a simple cross correlation-based registration is enough.

[image]

```
from skimage.registration import phase_cross_correlation
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, plot, figure
import numpy as np


# Load images
img_a = imread("671OL.jpg", as_gray=True)
img_b = imread("zpevD.jpg", as_gray=True)

# apply threshold
th_img_a = img_a > threshold_otsu(img_a)
th_img_b = img_b > threshold_otsu(img_b)

# measure connected component
img_lable = label(th_img_a)
r_props = regionprops(img_lable)

figure(figsize=(15,7))
rows, cols = img_b.shape

# calculate the registration (shift) of the two images
flow = phase_cross_correlation(th_img_a, th_img_b)

# stack the images and trace the segments that connect the points
d=10
# a vertical white bar between the two pictures
vbar=np.ones((rows,d))
xshift = cols+d
dy,dx = flow[0]
dx=dx + xshift
imshow(np.hstack([img_a, vbar, img_b]), cmap='gray')
for rp in r_props:
    y0,x0 = rp.centroid
    x1 = x0 + dx
    y1 = y0 - dy
    if y1<rows and x1 < 2*cols + d:
        # filter out points that are not in img_b
        plot([x0,x1],[y0,y1], '--', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: While running ur code, I am getting this error 'cannot import name 'optical_flow_ilk' from 'skimage.registration (C:\Users\rp603\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\registration\__init__.py)''

Comment: remove it, it is not needed indeed. I removed the useless imports

Comment: What if, I can find the coordinates of each data point of each image and then based on coordinates, try to find the matching data point. but don't know how to do this.

Comment: You are right, and I think this script does exactly what you say: the label function "finds the points" in one image, the final loop in the script calculates the coordinates in the other image (now stacked on the right)

Comment: I ran the codes. Found the following issue. 1. The final figure is messy and almost impossible to identify which data point is connected to other image data point. Is it possible to have this image with distance and colour so that I can see this clearly?

Comment: 2. Image needs to be aligned first otherwise coordinates of images data points going to be wrong. How to solve this?  I cant find this in ur code.

Comment: Hello @Ravi, I have run the script again and it produces the same image I have pasted in the answer :)

In the final loop you can customize the line style and color (plot function) and add text if you want (with matplotlib).

Point 2: you can align the images from the knowledge of the translation (stored in the flow variable). If you want the exact code, look for registration tutorials or ask another question on stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229730/discussion-between-marcop-and-ravi).